# Docker: Can't login in my mariadb using phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, docker, phpmyadmin, mariadb

I am trying to build up a docker-compose file to run all components I need for my app. The app, mysql (mariadb) and phpmyadmin is running but I can't login to my database.

Following docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.7'

networks:
  laravel:

services:
  php:
    image: php:7.4-fpm
    build: .conf/php/
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '9000:9000'
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www
      - .conf/php/conf.d/error_reporting.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/error_reporting.ini
      - .conf/php/conf.d/custom.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/custom.ini
    networks:
      - laravel

  fpm:
    image: php:7.4-fpm
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www
    networks:
      - laravel

  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - 8000:80
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www
      - ./var/log/nginx:/var/log/nginx
      - .conf/nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    networks:
      - laravel

  mariadb:
    image: mariadb:latest
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    volumes:
      - mariadb-volume:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: "no"
      MYSQL_DATABASE: app
      MYSQL_USER: admin
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: secret
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
    networks:
      - laravel

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin
    container_name: pma
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: app
      PMA_HOST: mariadb
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
    ports:
      - '8081:80'
    networks:
      - laravel

volumes:
  mariadb-volume:
```

When I try to login, I get the following error:

```
 mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'admin'@'172.31.0.6' (using password: YES)
```

I tried to find a solution.. something like set up the right env vars for mysql or set up a bridge between mysql and phpmyadmin. I did the network bridge and I can't really see the problem with my env vars.

Any clue?

System: Windows 10

Edit:

Found the problem. I just did docker-compose down -v ( -v = Remove named volumes declared in the `volumes`                            section of the Compose file and anonymous volumes )

and it worked :)

Comment: Environment variables only work if the data volume is un-initialized. `MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD` `no` is actually a true value, they are only tested for empty/non-empty. Remove it as you have a `MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD` set.

Comment: found the issue. I edited my question with what helped me.

Answer (score 3):

May be you can set for phpmyadmin by this command:

```
phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin:latest
    container_name: pma
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: app
      PMA_HOST: mariadb
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
    ports:
      - '8081:80'
    networks:
      - laravel
```

Comment: You've added a default `:latest` to the tag. This isn't sufficient to change the result.

Comment: maybe you can try the danblack ask mr. fuad